# ostream must take exactly one argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am getting a compile error in my output stream operator and I cannot seem to find out how to fix it as I never received this error before:

```
linkedList.cpp:258: error: ‘std::ostream& linkedList<T>::operator<<(std::ostream&, linkedList<T>)’ must take exactly one argument
make: *** [linkedList.o] Error 1
```

Here is the definition of my `operator<<`

```
template <class T>
ostream& linkedList<T>::operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList<T> list)
{
    node *curr;
    curr=list.head;

    while(curr!=NULL )
    {
        output << curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Here it is in my header:

```
//ostream operator for printing the list
template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList<T> list);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should pass the linked list by reference.  I don't believe you want the compiler to pass a copy of the linked list on the stack to your function.  If you don't plan on modifying the list, pass it by constant reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined it as a member function, you have to define it as a free standing (probably friend) function, either

1. **outside your class**

   ```
   template <class U>
   ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList<U> list){...}
   ```

in which case you also have to declare it inside the class as

```
template <class U> // note the different type name 
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList<U> list)
```

or

2. **inside the class as**

   ```
   // no need for template, type is passed automatically the function is not templated anymore
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList list){...}
   ```

The difference between these 2 declarations is a bit subtle, but for your purpose both work equally well. And probably you want to pass `linkedList` by `const` reference, `linkedList<T>& list`.

---

**EDIT**

A common mistake is to just declare the friend operator inside the class as

```
template<typename T>
class linkedlist
{
    //....
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const linkList& list); // declaration only
}
```

then try to define it outside the class as

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const linkList<T>& list){...}
```

Guess what? The code will compile, but won't link, as the declaration inside the class declares a *non-template* function, one for each type `T` you pass to `linkList<T>`. Then, when you declare e.g. `linkList<int> lst`, and try `cout << lst`, the compiler will see the declaration of the friend, which for it looks like

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const linkList<int>& list);
```

and will try searching for its definition. However there is no definition in the rest of the header, only the template operator, so the linker isn't able to find the implementation and will spit a linker error. Live example [here](http://ideone.com/83ARhR).

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the error message. This function that you declared:

```
template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList<T> list);
```

is a *member* function of `linkedList<T>` that takes *two* arguments. All the binary operators (`+`, `*`, `<<`, ... all except for the call operator `()`), when defined as member functions, must take exactly one argument, hence the error. What you had intended to do was to declare a *non-member* function, *external* to the class:

```
template <typename T>
class linkedList { .. };

template <typename T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList<T> list) {
    // implementation
}
```

You could also define it as a non-member `friend` inside the class definition:

```
template <class T>
class linkedList {
    ...
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, linkedList list){
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```